# I have a Time Limit Exceeded error in C. How do I overcome it?

Tags: c

c performance profiling time-limiting Details of the purpose of writing the program is given on the link : https://www.spoj.com/problems/CRCLE_UI/
And the error  Time limit exceeded

```
#include<stdio.h>

const int mod=1000000007;
int cal(int a, int b){
    long long x=1,y=a;
    while(b){
        if(b&1)x=x*y;
        if(x>=mod)x=x-(x/mod)*mod;
        y=y*y;
        if(y>=mod)y=y-(y/mod)*mod;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return x;
}
int main(){
    int t, n, k;
    long long ans,a1;
    for(scanf("%d",&t);t--;){
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);;t--;
        k--;
        if(k>=mod)k%=mod;
        ans=(long long)k;
        if(n&1)ans=ans*(-1);
        a1=cal((int)k,n);
        printf("%lld\n",(a1+ans+mod)%mod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program is too slow, or it contains an infinite loop and never properly terminates. The problem is in your code, which we can't see.

Comment: @tadman Thank you, here I have updated by entering my program code.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please format your code properly, it will help you with reading/understanding your code and finding bugs. don't put the then part of an `if` behind the `if`. Also what is this supposed to do even? `for(scanf("%d",&t);t--;)` for loops are build out of:  `for(variable; guard; increment/decrement)` you don't have a variable or a guard and don't do a increment/decrement. Of course it doesn't end.

Comment: You might need a different approach than iterating to calculate the number of *combinations* of n element from k choice with some repetition

Answer (score 1):

The problem is designed so that it is impossible to compute a result directly by exponentiating with n. Any such attempt will exceed the available resources. You must solve the problem using some number theory, particularly [Fermat’s Little Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Additionally, you cannot use `scanf` to process the input numerals but must read them yourself character by character and reduce them using number theory.

Answer (score 0):

Why the second `t--` on this line?

```
scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);;t--;
```

Getting rid of it allows the program to halt for any value of `t` (even and odd, so long as they're positive). Remember, the for loop's condition, `t--`, tests if `t` is 0. If it's any non-zero value, it'll evaluate to true.

What your code did was essentially make it so that any odd-number entered as `t` will never evaluate to 0. Take 1 for example: it's scanned in, `t--` in the for condition decrements it, the above line decrements it, so the next time the loop is evaluated `t == -1`, which evaluates to true. Every iteration after that will just be a more negative number, never 0.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried it on SPOJ but the results are still the same.  Time is limited.

Comment: did you notice this line? `for(scanf("%d",&t);t--;)` the loop never ends and never calls `break` so it is an infinite loop.