# I have a Time Limit Exceeded error in Program C. How do I overcome it?

Tags: c, loops, compiler-errors, integer, long-integer

c performance profiling time-limiting Details of the purpose of writing the program is given on the link : https://www.spoj.com/problems/CRCLE_UI/
And the error Time limit exceeded

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int T;
    long long a,b,hasil=1;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while (T--){
        scanf("%lld %lld",&a,&b);
        for (int i=b;i>(b-a);i--){
            hasil=hasil*i;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",hasil);
        hasil = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Essential information should not be in some external link.

Comment: Why did you post the exact same question twice, related to the exact same excercise, but with completely different source code!? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811741/i-have-a-time-limit-exceeded-error-in-c-how-do-i-overcome-it

Comment: Besides the accuracy of the algo, you have `int i = b` which is `long long...`, so you might simply ending up with an infinite loop... Try `long long i=b;...`

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio C

Comment: The problem is designed so that it is impossible to compute a result directly by exponentiating with n. Any such attempt will exceed the available resources. You must solve the problem using some number theory, particularly [Fermat’s Little Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Additionally, you cannot use `scanf` to process the input numerals but must read them yourself character by character and reduce them using number theory.

Answer (score 1):

> "*How do I overcome it?*"

```
for (int i = b; i > (b - a); i--) { ...
```

Change `int i` to `long long i` or at least `long i`. This solves the "*Killed - processing time exceeded*" error at my testings with your code.

[Online Example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaXAKylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgAnKQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OrrLyinQMBMzEBH56BpzGsZgKPonJBGE29o4uMkkpaQGZ5QVFEVEuAJQyqNrEyBwA5ACkAEwAzJbIOlgA1D0D6tIE%2BKgAdAiT2D0ADACCa%2BuWBGO6zJYQTVs9AOwAQltj12M7YwAqk5cbN2OsdMBvH2PMpHakCGYXlYkwAIpwnlcbtIWLQqBB%2Bn1%2BoZ0IjSP0AGz3Y4DZ6bF43ADuCDw7DGEHuAFpKccLlDXtcYSJ4YjkaxWOgJn1DOzUX0%2Bui%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%2BxTLpW1IDCSr858ux7PsBwKkdxwgJA2gINwIPnCBFxnTLBAEpLFNIbDGBYD8CMJRC3Ew5s0zbfzU2yzgxkJQgEDGIKQrCiKopiuL8qHQqEEwZgsCcI4iq4VZSpbDMqv7dtc1Ter%2B0HGt60bQx5m4U4hUC5xVlOQwMQGVYmzKgYFtql7GqO5r4FHCdeuXbqUf6qLiLXG6Rq3HdKH3Z8j1oU9UMvKdr3oe9H0/V8RGAD9n3wH9cgAoCO1A8DIOfaCyo7SjEOIE9kO6C9uLwDCugrLC6DGvCuF4AQBSx0jJCEeDqMuuiGKY5jMAAoWCBJURRLiCSIFMezZPMJyGl05SQl8EzqgdhjrPt8y8js52ZM9wzHPCBSzO9/xfaM93XNaDz8O8%2Baao7ALgtC8KRnp/bVnmVYEvwIgssGVL0r6xwyz6XL1EOj6roGAZ5mruv64buaKoe%2BPnu7GQGve4ckdakB2s6gg0anIunAFQbc8EUbcIm3gpuYGapeHMrfKezslsGeK1qNzak521P5VijOOy747TvOyhY%2BbkBqtXuqO7egrPr6bh5kMPpTnLVZ124AYMWcYG5pQ1bmvduJ8EawCQJzZAEESDdWSMAaQAAFEQcgGAIFQISLMF50bMAYsgqwrA0EYNXujUoq5OCrCUqQ4gt4IJEMwZ%2BKB6xiAINhlAxI%2BAsynAmH6WgYwKE3UEVnX0/oxglSETw/0GYp7jXworIi9NVbkXVlReAtF6I%2BCAj2YsnlbKcPwag9BDD4bL2hgnVMW1k67WihQ%2BYK1sBgWgbnbOQ0UplwrkmJ%2BxgyoVVvrDXsD8jqxz6GYtuHjCoGy8MobgQAhttps://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaXAKylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgAnKQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OrrLyinQMBMzEBH56BpzGsZgKPonJBGE29o4uMkkpaQGZ5QVFEVEuAJQyqNrEyBwA5ACkAEwAzJbIOlgA1D0D6tIE%2BKgAdAiT2D0ADACCa%2BuWBGO6zJYQTVs9AOwAQltj12M7YwAqk5cbN2OsdMBvH2PMpHakCGYXlYkwAIpwnlcbtIWLQqBB%2Bn1%2BoZ0IjSP0AGz3Y4DZ6bF43ADuCDw7DGEHuAFpKccLlDXtcYSJ4YjkaxWOgJn1DOzUX0%2Bui%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%2BxTLpW1IDCSr858ux7PsBwKkdxwgJA2gINwIPnCBFxnTLBAEpLFNIbDGBYD8CMJRC3Ew5s0zbfzU2yzgxkJQgEDGIKQrCiKopiuL8qHQqEEwZgsCcI4iq4VZSpbDMqv7dtc1Ter%2B0HGt60bQx5m4U4hUC5xVlOQwMQGVYmzKgYFtql7GqO5r4FHCdeuXbqUf6qLiLXG6Rq3HdKH3Z8j1oU9UMvKdr3oe9H0/V8RGAD9n3wH9cgAoCO1A8DIOfaCyo7SjEOIE9kO6C9uLwDCugrLC6DGvCuF4AQBSx0jJCEeDqMuuiGKY5jMAAoWCBJURRLiCSIFMezZPMJyGl05SQl8EzqgdhjrPt8y8js52ZM9wzHPCBSzO9/xfaM93XNaDz8O8%2Baao7ALgtC8KRnp/bVnmVYEvwIgssGVL0r6xwyz6XL1EOj6roGAZ5mruv64buaKoe%2BPnu7GQGve4ckdakB2s6gg0anIunAFQbc8EUbcIm3gpuYGapeHMrfKezslsGeK1qNzak521P5VijOOy747TvOyhY%2BbkBqtXuqO7egrPr6bh5kMPpTnLVZ124AYMWcYG5pQ1bmvduJ8EawCQJzZAEESDdWSMAaQAAFEQcgGAIFQISLMF50bMAYsgqwrA0EYNXujUoq5OCrCUqQ4gt4IJEMwZ%2BKB6xiAINhlAxI%2BAsynAmH6WgYwKE3UEVnX0/oxglSETw/0GYp7jXworIi9NVbkXVlReAtF6I%2BCAj2YsnlbKcPwag9BDD4bL2hgnVMW1k67WihQ%2BYK1sBgWgbnbOQ0UplwrkmJ%2BxgyoVVvrDXsD8jqxz6GYtuHjCoGy8MobgQA)

---

*Note: I´m currently searching why this error comes up with `int i`.*

Comment: `int i` gets the complaint because `b - a` can easily exceed the range of `int` by orders of magnitude -- leading to signed integer overflow -- UB.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicCellio Thanks for the answer, i tried it on SPOJ  But the results are still the same, time is limited.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio are there any other solutions?

Comment: Huh, I just checked on gcc 10.1.0 -- and I don't get any complaint -- we will have to wait on your research `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Seems that I misinterpreted the error as compilation error :-| But I still wonder why the error occurs before any input is provided. It seems that the online server detects the lack in the algorithm before the execution takes place and therefore throw the error "*Killed - processing time exceeded*".

Comment: The problem statement shows that n and k may each have a thousand digits. Changing `int` to `long long` might change the behavior of the program from running too long to producing incorrect results, particularly in the test cases you and/or the OP is using, but it will not fix the program so that it solves the posed problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Do you mean `a` and `b` instead of `n` and `k`? I don´t quite understand what you mean with that they may have a thousand digits. - I asked the OP before if s/he provided any input at execution. - The problem seems to occur before any input takes place. Or do you mean that they are initialized by a number of 1000 digits? - I´m also not quite sure what Fermat's little theorem, as posted in your comment under the question, has to do with it. Do you mean that `hasil = hasil * i;`instead of `int i = b; i > (b - a);` is the problem?

Comment: The problem statement linked to in the question uses n and k rather than a and b. It says they may have values up to 10^1000, hence a thousand significant digits. Fermat’s Little Theorem is needed to reduce the problem, along with other techniques.